# Azure B2C ajax authentication check

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Current situation: symfony application with authentication via azure AD B2C.

How is it possible to make an authorize check to [https://TENTANT.b2clogin.com/TENTANT.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize via ajax to verify if a customer has an active session on azure AD, i only need to retrieve the azure oid from the token.

Now i redirect the user to [https://TENTANT.b2clogin.com/TENTANT.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_sign_in&client_id=CLIENTID&none=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=REDIRECTURI&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login&response_mode=form_post&ui_locales=en but i want to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSAL method ssosilent(), which opens the auth endpoint via hidden iframe. That succeeds only if there is a valid session cookie at AAD B2C. Note this only works if your app and AAD B2C are on the same root domain name.